# If all applicants are motivated professionals, and some professionals are unmotivated, then ...

Tags: logic, puzzle

A friend of mine took an aptitude test by Deloitte. One of the questions was an interesting logical puzzle:

> - All applicants are motivated professionals
> - Some professionals are unmotivated
>
> Select the correct answer:
>
> 1) engineers are unmotivated
>
> 2) some applicants are unmotivated
>
> 3) some professionals are applicants
>
> 4) none of these conclusions is logically inescapable

Thinking purely mathematically, the answer was clear to me, and so it was to my mathematics friends. However, my friend and her friends seem to interpret the question a little bit different. It's interesting to see the different approaches to this question.

Unfortunately, we were not able to see the correct answer. What do you think?

Comment: "*unnoticed*"?  Or *unmotivated*?

Comment: sorry, auto correct for some reason. also edited answer 3)

Comment: One of the conclusions is "logically inescapable."  Do you have any real doubt of the answer?  You should explain your concern more fully.

Comment: which one would be logically inescapable? id choose 4)

Comment: And now you've changed the options.  Technically, we aren't told that there exist any applicants.  Only that if there did exist any that they would need to be motivated professionals.  The second statement does imply that there are professionals and that at least some of them (*possibly all*) are unmotivated.  If it happened to be the case that we know there exist applicants, then I would agree with (3) that some professionals are applicants, however since we aren't guaranteed that there exist any applicants in the first place I would say none of the above.

Comment: i think Venn diagrams can be useful here. I would say statement 2 is correct.

Comment: but all applicants are motivated, it cant be true

Comment: right. I misread. my bad

Comment: @NicolaZaugg Please consider accepting an answer if it satisfactorily answers the question for you

Answer (score 2):

If we take the help of a Venn diagram:
[image]

Statement 1 says that: "engineers are unmotivated"
This isn't necessarily true as we cannot say anything about engineers(no information provided)

Statement 2 says that : "Some applicants are unmotivated"
This is clearly false as it can be seen in the diagram. All applicants are motivated.

Statement 3 says that: "Some professionals are applicants"
This can be true as our set of applicants come under the set of motivated **professionals**

---

**Note**: I have assumed that there exist applicants to begin with. (The question doesn't mention otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

There's wiggle room in the statements, of course. Does "engineers are unmotivated" mean "all engineers are unmotivated" or "some engineers are unmotivated"? Is an engineer a professional or not?

But anyway, we can't say anything.

If engineers don't have to be professionals:

Consider a world with no applicants; exactly one unmotivated professional, who is not an engineer; and exactly one engineer, who is motivated. Then the preconditions hold, but none of the postconditions.

If all engineers are professionals: consider a world with no applicants, one motivated engineer, and one unmotivated non-engineer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

PS: I was uploading the picture when I saw the prompt answer of @sai-kartik

Comment: How have you reached the conclusion for engineers? Was it just an assumption you made?

Comment: I have drawn the most "uninformative prior": Bayesian approach. In fact, with the info given you cannot decide whether "(1) engineers are unmotivated" is true or false.

Comment: i think (according to the comments) some of the options were changed